# What is the meaning of angle brackets?

Tags: notation

I have this formula:

$\Delta a_{ki} \propto v_k (v_i - \langle v_i \rangle_{recon})$

First, what does $\propto$ mean and second, what is the difference between $v_i$ and $\langle v_i \rangle$?

Comment: $\propto$ means "proportional to" here: You found out the markup for that, which is a strong clue: see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_symbols. Angle brackets can indicate means; that's dubious here. In any case, giving a source for your quotation never hurts and is often useful.

Comment: I removed the "matrix" tag and added "notation". I don't see a matrix flavour to either question.

Comment: Notation tends to inherit from mathematics, but different application areas tend to use notation in somewhat different ways. There are a number of things the angle brackets might mean (or it might mean something I'm not even aware of).

Comment: The angle brackets usually denote an expectation.